# regex match specific letters and exclude rest of letter

Tags: php, regex

```
$string='letters=ABCD';
```

We want to match `"letters="` and letter `B` or `C`. The letter in string may input as:

- B
- C
- BC
- CB
  How to filter out A and D and output result as letters=BC ?

`preg_match('/(letters=([BC]+))/', $string,$matches);`

- This match if letter in string start letter B or C and can filter out D
- not work when letter start other letter

`preg_match('/&lt;FORMAT=[A-Z]+[BIU]+/', $string,$matches);`

- The result not filter out A in result

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kMAZlR/1

Comment: this solution works. But for this, we need to list the possible arrangement. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I wrote that based on your question. I am still a little confused as to what are the inputs and it's respective expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
(?:^letters=|\G(?!^))[BC]*\K[AD-Z]+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSy26P/1)

---

- `(?:^letters=|\G(?!^))` - Non-capture group to match the start of the input as literally 'letters=' *or* assert position at end of previous match but negate start of string;
- `[BC]*` - 0+ times the letters 'B' or 'C';
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match;
- `[AD-Z]+` - Match 1+ uppercase letters in range 'AD-Z'.

---

Replace with empty string:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:^letters=|\G(?!^))[BC]*\K[AD-Z]+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Nice use of `\G`.

Comment: if string `<letters=ABCD>` has open and closing tag , `>` should placed in (?!^`>`) ? Full expression :`/(?:^<letters=|\G(?!^>))[BC]*\K[AD-Z]+/`

Comment: @Premlatha, if that's the only other option, then just make the open less-than-symbol optional?

Comment: @JvdV, less than and more than symbol not optional.

Comment: Then, if you still want to validate then whole input including these symbols, use `(?:^<letters=(?=.+>$)|\G(?!^))[BC]*\K[AD-Z]+`. If you don't need to validate the closing symbol, just scratch the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you can replace every match of the following regular expression with an empty string.

```
^.*'(?=(?:letters|LETTERS)=[A-Z]+';$)|[AD-Z](?!.*=)|';$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OQodrF/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^             match beginning of string
.*            match zero or more chars other than line terminators
'             match literal
(?=           begin a positive lookahead
  (?:         begin a non-capture group
    letters   match literal
  |           or
    LETTERS   match literal
  )           end the non-capture group
  =           match literal
  [A-Z]+      match one or more uppercase letters
  ';          match literal
  $           match end of string
)             end the positive lookahead 
|             or
[AD-Z]        match a capital letter other than 'B' or 'C'
(?!           begin a negative lookahead
  .*          match zero or more chars other than line terminators
  =           match literal
)             end the negative lookahead
|             or
';            match literal
$             match the end of the string
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried this. when `letters` words in `letters=ABCD` appear as uppercase as `LETTERS=ABCD`. It replace the letter in `LETTERS` also

Comment: You didn't mention in the question that `letters` could appear in uppercase. I modified my answer to permit `letters` or `LETTERS`. It's curious that @JvdV made the same assumption as I did that `letters` was lowercase, and his regex also fails for `LETTERS`, yet you selected his answer without complaint. I'm not challenging your decision to award the checkmark to him. I would have done the same as it's an excellent answer.

Comment: Its my mistake for not stating in question. Thank you for your answer.